# Detect support for PHP from within .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, cgi, fastcgi

In a web application I'm packaging for Debian, I would like a set of rewrite rules to be effective only if PHP is supported by the webserver. I thought of wrapping my rules in an `<IfModule>` block to check mod `mod_php`, but that won't work if the PHP intepreter is accessed through CGI.

Comment: Do you want your application to also be usable when running nginx?

Comment: Sure, but since nginx doesn't read `.htaccess`, it's a bit off-topic for this question, no?

Comment: That's why I asked ;-) Depending on .htaccess files would make you project less portable.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand, I'm looking for directives which could also be used in a standard Apache configuration. I suppose I wouldn't mind an answer about nginx, it might help someone else or myself in the future, but I won't tag the question as solved.